# How do I convert a array into a string using str(a[i]) in python

Tags: python

I can convert an array into a string using `str.join` but my assignment asks me too convert each element of the array using `str(a[i])` and then append them together.

I am completely lost on how to do this. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: So... [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Let's say if a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
I tried str(a) but that just gives me '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'. When I try str([1]) I just get '1'. (All of which makes sense.) I'm stuck at how get rid of the brackets and commas and for whatever reason I can't find out how to do that using str(a) or append. I guess what im asking is how can I get rid of the formatting and just have it return '12345678910'. Again, Sorry if I'm not making sense or if I'm leaving stuff out I'm new to this whole programming thing.

Answer (score 7):

you're trying to do :

```
>>> str(lis)
'[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
```

which is wrong, because you need to apply `str()` to individual elements not the datastructure itself(equivalent to `lis.__str__()`), so loop through the elements and apply `str()` to individual elements.

**solutions:**

A readable version:

```
>>> lis1=[]
>>> for item in lis:
    lis1.append(str(item))         #append the `str()` version of each item to lis1

>>> lis1
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']       

>>> ''.join(lis1)
'12345'
```

using  generator:

```
>>> ''.join(str(x) for x in lis)
'12345'
```

using `map()`:

```
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> ''.join(map(str,lis))
'12345'
```

`map()` applies the function passed as first argument to every item of the iterable passed as second argument, and returns a list(returns a map object in python 3.x)

Comment: Thank you! This is a really great community, it's astonishing to me to see how quickly I received responses. My code seems to be working. I have one question though, the assignment was:

"Write a function, to_str(a), that takes an array, a, converts each of its elements to a string (using str(a[i])) and appends all these strings together."

Would using the str.join function be considered using append?

Comment: @iamtesla You're welcome, I would use the  word `concatenate` with `str.join`, `append` is related to lists.

Comment: I would have suggested map last. Comprehensions and expressions are the modern Pythonic way to do it; the explicit array is the old-school Pythonic way (and easier to understand for newcomers to the language); map is the way that Guido grudgingly accepted into the language and has been trying to push out ever since…

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're starting with a list `a`, create a new (empty) list `b`.  Loop over elements of `a` appending `str(element)` to `b` at each iteration.  use `str.join` on b.  Smile.